# Can't register Mediatr automatically trough structuremap IoC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap, cqrs, mediatr, multi-layer

I have a web application with multilayer architecture and the classes of handlers and queries in the separate layer from a structuremap configuration. I tried to register all handlers and queries dynamically but I couldn't.When I try to run the application I receive the runtime error:

No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IRequestHandler'
There is no configuration specified for IRequestHandler

```
        public DefaultRegistry() {
        Scan(
            scan => {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<DefaultRegistry>();
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<IMediator>();
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IAsyncRequestHandler<,>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRequestHandler<>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IAsyncRequestHandler<>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(INotificationHandler<>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IAsyncNotificationHandler<>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>));
                scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
            });
        //For<IExample>().Use<Example
        For<SingleInstanceFactory>().Use<SingleInstanceFactory>(ctx => t => ctx.GetInstance(t));
        For<MultiInstanceFactory>().Use<MultiInstanceFactory>(ctx => t => ctx.GetAllInstances(t));
        For<IMediator>().Use<Mediator>();
        For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<UnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs<TransientLifecycle>();
        For(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>)).DecorateAllWith(typeof(Business.Pipeline.MediatorPipeline<,>));
    }
```

controller 
`var query = new GetUserQuery(id);var user = _mediator.Send(query);`

query

```
    public class GetUserQuery : IRequest<User>
{
    public GetUserQuery() { }
    public GetUserQuery(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

handler

```
 public class GetUserHandler : IRequestHandler<GetUserQuery, User>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    public GetUserHandler(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public User Handle(GetUserQuery message)
    {
        return _uow.UserRepository.Get(message.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this all in one assembly (project?)

Comment: @Alex No, in different

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like

```
scan.AssemblyContainingType<GetUserHandler>();
```

To your registry

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**
I've added to Scan method few commands for scanning other projects from the solution, after that, I called method LookForRegistries. If you want scan types and implementations in other projects you need to set the rule of scanning specific dlls in Scan method.

```
                    scan.Assembly("NameOfProj.Business");
                scan.Assembly("NameOfProj.Persistence");
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<DefaultRegistry>();
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IAsyncRequestHandler<,>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRequestHandler<>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IAsyncRequestHandler<>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(INotificationHandler<>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IAsyncNotificationHandler<>));
                scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>));
                scan.LookForRegistries();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
```

Comment: you can use AssemblyContainingType, as per my answer